# Keep gradient the same when changing background image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I have a background image that I want to change every 10 seconds. However, I have a gradient on top of that image, that I dont want to change when i change the image. This is the original css:

```
#carBanner 
{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 100%), url('TS12-COVER.jpg');
}
```

Then I have javascript that has a function that is called every 10 seconds, the function looks like this:

```
function changeImage()
{
    document.getElementById('carBanner').style.background = "url('haegri.png')";
}
```

When i do this, the gradient no longer appears on top of the picture.. I have also tried this:

```
function changeImage()
{
    document.getElementById('carBanner').style.background = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 100%), url('haegri.png');"
}
```

But then the image wont change. 
Can anyone please tell me how i can change the background image and still keep the gradient? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `style.background` will affect all properties of `background`. However if you specifically want to target `backgroundImage` please use below mentioned code.

```
function changeImage()
{
    document.getElementById('carBanner').style.backgroundImage = "url('haegri.png')";
}
```

Update:

Since this method does not seem to work, I am posting this fiddle on lines as mentioned by kush. This method seems to work as long as you just want to swap between 2 images.

It basically uses 2 classes with two different background images. On click instead of changing just image, previous class gets removed and new class is applied.

http://jsfiddle.net/gtej2/

I will still looking for more elegant solution and will update fiddle soon.

Comment: This still makes the gradient disappear.

Comment: It works now. Thanks. Please let me know if you find a cleaner solution :)

Comment: @GudrunOlafs : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20048466/2940964 is clearner knowing that you can use the number of img you want with only one css image class

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS classes to control this behavior, you can add or remove class from your element in javascript. You CSS class can have your settings of background and gradient.

Answer (score 0):

For the image use:

`background-image`

Or in your code:

`.style.backgroundImage` ...

Comment: I tried that, like Gaurav suggested above, and still the gradient disappears.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an overlay? You place a div on which you are setting the image and another div over it on which you set your gradient.

Therefore you would have to set correctly your overlay, but with JS it's quite easy:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Set the overlay over the image slider
    var left = $("#test").offset().left;
    var top = $("#test").offset().top;
    $("#overlay").css('left', left + 'px');
    $("#overlay").css('top', top + 'px');

    // Change your image
    setInterval(changeImage,1000);
});
```

This would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/Tj7j5/1/